# Creating a variable in env and using it in blade, error

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create a variable in .env file and then I can use it in other blades.

The real path is this:

```
 <img src="http://localhost/myy_project/storage/app/public/thumbs/{{$trip->image}}" class="img-responsive" alt="tour-img" />
```

But I want to try using .env

```
IMAGE_PATH=http://localhost/myy_project/storage/app/public/
```

blade:

```
   <img  src="{{env('IMAGE_PATH')}}thumbs/{{$trip->image}}" class="img-responsive" alt="tour-img" />
```

When I use .env the image isn't shown. Where might be the problem ?

Comment: Try this in env file IMAGE_PATH="http://localhost/my_project/storage/app/public"

Comment: If you look at the browser source, what does the src URL say? And shouldn't the period after thumbs be a slash?

Comment: nothing happend

Comment: if you're using artisan, don't forget to stop and restart when changing your .env

Comment: or clear your app cache `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: If you inspect the image in the browser, what is the actual markup output?

Comment: "Nothing happened" doesn't tell us much. Find the img src in the page source, and tell us exactly what is says.

Comment: @nyu.exe  I did, but  nothing happend

Answer (score 0):

```
{{env('IMAGE_PATH')}}/thumbs.{{$trip->image}}
```

According to your description, I think the `.` after 'thumbs' is `/`, it seems like that your `IMAGE_PATH` does not contains 'thumbs'.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say without knowing what the actual `<img/>` markup is that's being output, but it could be that your `.env` file is out of date.

This can happen if you're using `php artisan serve` during development. In this case, restarting the dev server will reload your `.env` file so that your application can access the new `IMAGE_PATH` option.

#### Edit

You might try running `php artisan view:clear` to make sure you're not seeing an old compiled copy of the view. Other relevant commands include `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear` to flush the config and application caches respectively.

Ideally though, you probably want to avoid using `env()` in your views. Instead, you could add a line to your *config/app.php* such as:

```
    'image_path' => env('IMAGE_PATH'),
```

then reference it like this:

```
<img src="{{ config('app.image_path') }}thumbs/{{ $trip->image }}" class="img-responsive" alt="tour-img" />
```

With all that said, if your image path will always be the public folder, you can simply use the [public_path](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-public-path) helper:

```
<img src="{{ public_path('thumbs/'.$trip->image) }}" class="img-responsive" alt="tour-img" />
```

Comment: I tried to restart the server, but still images aren't showed

Comment: @Alphal1111 What output do you see if you right-click and Inspect the image?

Comment: @Alphal1111 I've just updated my answer to add some extra commands to clear caches, along with better ways to achieve what you're trying to do. Give it a try and let me know how you get on